# React Navigator won't navigate to screen

Tags: react-native

I have made a stack navigation for showing vouchers.

```js
const screens:any = {
  ListActiveVouchers: {
    screen: ListActiveVouchersScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: <Header title='Håndter bilag'/>
    }
  },
  ShowVoucher: {
    screen: ShowVoucherScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: <Header title='Vis bilag'/>
    },
  },
  ShowNotesScreen: {
    screen: ShowNotesScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: <Header title='Noter'/>
    }
  },

  RejectVoucherScreen: {
    screen: RejectVoucherScreen,
  },

}

export const ActiveVouchersStack = createStackNavigator(screens);
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'; 
import {GlobalStyles} from '../style/GlobalStyles';

const RejectVoucherScreen = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Afvis bilag</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default RejectVoucherScreen;
```

When I'm on the show voucher screen, I am unable to navigate to `RejectVoucherScreen`, but I am however able to navigate to the show notes screen...

Can someone explain why I can go to one, but not the other?

Comment: Add your RejectVoucherScreen component here

Comment: aded it to original post

Comment: what about adding navigationOptions in your RejectVoucherScreen stack.

Comment: Aha!.... i see, so you need the navigation prop to be able to navigate